# dk pdf generator for huge tables

Tags: css, wordpress, coordination

I have used dk pdf generator in my wordpress site but I have a problem with huge tables that I have 
for huge tables I need to change orientation page of that page 
for example if I have an article 5 page and the table is in second page , I want set ordination of all pages portrait except second page
for example you can Visit [Here](https://dev.nu-agrar.de/grune_info/herbizide-in-wintergetreide-zur-herbstanwendung-2018-info-19-18/)
the ck pdf generator has support css 
any one can solve my problem.
thanks all you.

Comment: Please, post your code so i can help you

Comment: @Matheus i added dk pdf generator to wp site , i have no code , can you gave me a css for changing page ordination that have huge tables?